# Is this true? $\forall x\exists y ((x + y \in X) \vee (x - y)\in Z)$

Tags: set-theory

U = $\begin{Bmatrix}
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
\end{Bmatrix}$

X = $\begin{Bmatrix}
0,1,2,3,4
\end{Bmatrix}$

Z = $\begin{Bmatrix}
1,3,5,7,9
\end{Bmatrix}$

Is this true?
$\forall x\exists y ((x + y \in X) \vee  (x - y)\in Z)$

**My solution:**  (Before this i tried with y = 1 and y = 2)

**y=3**

x = 1 y = 3 --> 1+3 = 4 --> (X)

x = 2 y = 3 --> 3-2 = 1 --> (Z)

x = 3 y = 3 --> 3-3 = 0 --> (Z)

x = 4 y = 3 --> 4-3 = 1 --> (Z)

x = 5 y = 3 --> 5+3=8 or 5-3 = 2

So  y = 3 is not true because 8 is not in (X) and 2 is not in (Z).

Do i need to test this for every  other y = 4,5,6...9 to verify if this is true or not? Or is there a better faster way to do this?

Comment: Just one example of $y$ is not enough, if you want to show that the statement is not true, you have to find an $x$ such that no $y$ exists to satisfy the above statment. Quick question, is $x \in X$ or $x \in U$?

Comment: A specific $y$ doesn't interests you. Because you first "get" or "choose" an arbitary $x$. Just THEN you determine $y$.
If you wold like to show it like in your solution in the hard long way, you need to get every $x$ (NOT $y$) and show that there's one specific $y$ that valid your statement.

Comment: I asked if $x\in U$ in one of your other questions and you didn't reply.  You also haven't replied to @Dashi's question in the comment above.  Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement says, in plain english:

> For *every* $x$ there *exists* a $y$ such that either $x+y$ is in $X$ or $x-y$ is in $Z$.

Therefore, you must prove the statement for all values of $x$, but the $y$ value doesn't need to be the same.

For $x=1,2,3,4$, you can select $y=3$.

For $x=5$, the value $y=3$ is not good, but that doesn't mean there doesn't exist some other value of $y$ that is good. In fact, if $x=5$, we can take $y=4$ to prove that the statement holds for $x=5$.

Comment: Okay thanks I understand :)

Comment: So i guess this is true? For example if we pick 1 + 3 = 4, 3 - 2 = 1, 3 - 3 = 0, 4 -3 = 1, 5 -2 = 3, 6 - 1 = 5, 7 - 2 = 5, 8 - 3 = 5, 9 - 0 = 9

Comment: @DanielAndersson I don't really understand your "proof". You should make it more clear to show which $x$ value you are currently proving the statement for.

Comment: Did you find it true?

Comment: @DanielAndersson Like I said, I don't understand your proof, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: I mean did you find this true with your proof?

Comment: @DanielAndersson Yes, the statement is true.

Answer (score 2):

First, the statement you are considering is $\forall x \in U \left( \exists y \in U \left( \left( x + y \right) \in X \vee \left( x - y \right) \in Z \right) \right)$.

Observe that if $x \in X$ or $x \in Z$, then $y = 0 \in U$ works. For the other numbers, namely $6$ and $8$ observe that $6 - 5 = 1 \in Z$ and $8 - 7 = 1 \in Z$. Hence, the statement is true.

First, you need to "choose" an $x \in U$ and then corresponding to this you need to "find" a $y \in U$ so that either the sum is in $X$ or the difference is in $Z$. What you were trying to do in your attempt was that for every pair of elements $x$ and $y$ in $U$, you were trying to figure out if the sum was in $X$ or the difference was in $Z$. This is not to be done for the statement we have.

Comment: I had wondered what $U$ was doing in the problem statement.   Good inference.